# Pivot melted Pandas DataFrame back to wide view?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot

I have a `DataFrame` called `df` that looks like the following: (where all values are strings):

```
        id        type       variable
---------------------------------------------
         A         a          item_1
         A         a          item_2
         A         a          item_3
         A         b          item_4
         A         b          item_5
         A         b          item_6
         A         c          item_7
         A         c          item_8
         A         c          item_9
```

I want to convert it to look like:

```
type  a                     |b                       |c
id
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

A     item_1|item_2|item_3 | item_4 | item_5 |item_6| item_7 |item_8 | item_9
```

Basically, I want columns `type` and `variable` to be arranged in multilevel column. This is obviously a snapshot, but basically I have 9 different values for each `id` in `df`

I've tried the following code:

```
df.pivot(index = 'id', columns = 'type', values = 'variable')
```

But get the following error:

```
ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```

I'm sure there is a fairly simple solution and I'm just not thinking of it! I would appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a helper key (By using `cumcount`)here for remove the error `Index contains duplicate`

```
df.assign(helpkey=df.groupby('type').cumcount()).set_index(['id','type','helpkey']).variable.unstack([-2,-1])
Out[138]: 
type          a                       b                       c          \
helpkey       0       1       2       0       1       2       0       1   
id                                                                        
A        item_1  item_2  item_3  item_4  item_5  item_6  item_7  item_8   
type             
helpkey       2  
id               
A        item_9
```

Also we can using `crosstab`

```
pd.crosstab(index=df.id,columns=[df.type,df.groupby('type').cumcount()],values=df.variable,aggfunc='sum')
Out[144]: 
type        a                       b                       c                
col_1       0       1       2       0       1       2       0       1       2
id                                                                           
A      item_1  item_2  item_3  item_4  item_5  item_6  item_7  item_8  item_9
```

Or `pivot_table` :

```
df.assign(helpkey=df.groupby('type').cumcount()).pivot_table(index='id',columns=['type','helpkey'],values='variable', aggfunc='sum')
```

Comment: Such a complete answer.  +1

Comment: @Wen thanks for the detailed response. The output actually shows a bunch of None values because it looks like with each row, it's adding 9 more columns to the right. I want the dimensions to be N (number of unique ids) x 9. Any other ideas?

Comment: @AlisonLT then you should have mutiple Id right ? Try this `df.assign(helpkey=df.groupby(['id','type']).cumcount()).set_index(['id','type','helpkey']).variable.unstack([-2,-1])
`, also if this is what you need , would you mind consider upvote and accept it ?

Comment: @Wen THANK YOU - you are awesome!! Worked perfectly